# Find a pyramid containing a given cuboid under some constraints.

Tags: geometry, problem-solving

Can someone help out with this geometry problem plase?

I have a pyramid $P$ with square basis and each of its 4 triangles is equilateral. I also have cuboid $C$ with height 25 and width 50, something like this:

[image]

So the volume of $C$ is $25 . 50 . 50 = 62500$

I need to find out how big the square base of $P$ must be in order for $P$ to fully contain $C$ with the bottom of $C$ being at distance $26$ from the square base of $P$.Basically the cube must be fully inside the pyramid and to hand $26$ units above the pyramid's floor.

Can someone give advice on how to solve this?I have no other info on the pyramid.Is it even possible to solve this with so little information?

Comment: For starters I'd draw a planar section of $P$ bisecting $C$ by a plane midway between a pair of faces. (In the end, the base of $P$ can be any length strictly larger than $50$, but the smaller the base of $P$ the taller $P$ has to be.)

Comment: @user86418 I tried splitting the pyramid into 3 parts, the top part $P_1$ ,continuing from the top of $C$, the middle part $P_2$ having its edges continue from the edges of $P_1$ until they reach the plane of $C$'s bottom base, then continue to $P_3$ which is the bottom part of the pyramid.However I don't have enough information to do anything with these parts.Is there a formula that finds the length of a line parallel to the pyramid's base, going from one edge to the next one?

Answer (score 1):

The suggested cross section is shown. Let $h$ be the height of the pyramid above the top of $C$and let $w$ be half the width of the base. By similar triangles,
$$
\frac{w}{h + 51} = \frac{25}{h},
\quad\text{or}\quad
 w = 25\left(1 + \frac{51}{h}\right).
$$

[image: longitudinal cross section]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Let the pyramid $ABCDE$ whose sides have length $L$. See figure 1.

[image]

**Figure 1**

The right angled triangles $\triangle ENF$ and $\triangle EMB$ are isosceles. (Check it out).

Using Pythagoras we get:
$$GF=50 \sqrt{2}$$ and $$DB=L \sqrt{2}$$.

So $NF=25 \sqrt{2}$ and $MB=\frac{L \sqrt{2}}{2}$.

As $EM=MB$ we get:
$$L=50+51 \sqrt{2}$$